# Images aren't Showing up?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding

My images are showing up in the design view, but not when I launch my project, it still shows the old images, although they don't exist anymore... Anyone know why it's doing this? I haven't changed any of the paths, I just replaced them with the new images. Any help will be apperciated. Thanks, Jason (btw I cleared my cache and I even tried changing my browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a "Clean Solution" and that worked, I just learned about that today